# Tkinter Treeview shows extra column

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I have a problem with my treeview that it inserts an extra column.

I create the treview with:
self.table = ttk.Treeview(frame, columns=columns, show='tree headings')

I know show='tree headings') gives you an extra column but I need show='tree headings') because I have a hierarchical treeview. Anyone who knows how to get rid of the extra column?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example, here is a link [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I guess you are talking about the #0 column(IIRC), you could set its width to 0